# Is there a HOSTS file on Symbian Series 60 5th Edition devices?

Tags: testing, networking, symbian, nokia, s60

There used to be a HOSTS file on S60 3rd edition devices (see [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Hosts_file_on_S60_3.x_Devices)). It was a great feature for QA.

Anyone knows if there's such a file on S60 5th edition devices?

Is there another way to tell the phone to go to a specific IP, given a host name?

Many thanks,

Ori

Comment: Doesn't the same mechanism as on 3rd work on 5th? Or is it just the platsec that prevents you from using it?

Comment: The HOSTS file is not there (checked with Y-Browser), so I assume it's a different implementation on 5th edition.

Comment: Hosts file not being there doesn't mean you couldn't put one in there. AFAIK, this thing has not changed between 3rd and 5th editions. It makes perfect sense not to have a hosts file by default; DNS is the sensible default for end-users.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the same idea, but I read on the Nokia's developer discussion boards a post by someone who tried just that with no success, so I didn't want to waste my time on this...

Here's the link to the thread I'm talking about, in case you're interested: http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?p=609875&postcount=4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... I guess the HOSTS file is not an option... in case anyone's encountered a similar problem, here's the solution I came up with to work-around this issue :)

I'm using Nokia 5800 XpressMusic and my QA server runs on a Mac.

1. installed a proxy server on my Mac (I used Squid)
2. configured my phone's WLAN access point to use the new proxy server
3. configured a "hostname.local" domain on my Mac (using the machine's HOSTS file)
4. accessed my QA server via the hostname.local domain from the phone over the phone's WiFi connection

works great...

If anybody knows a simpler solution, I'd still be happy to hear about it...

Ori